# signalr not working with solution angularjs+asp.net web api

Tags: signalr

here is my signalr piece on backend

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public void AddMessage(string userName, string message)
        {

            Clients.All.receivedNewMessage(userName, message);
        }
    }
```

and on frontend

```
 app.controller('chatController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

        var _message = function(id, message, username, date)
        {
           // this.id = id;
            this.message = message;
            this.username = username;
          //  this.date = date;

        }

    $scope.username = "test";
    $scope.message = "";

    $scope.messages = [];

        //auto proxy start
    $.connection.hub.url = "http://localhost:*****/signalr/";
    var myChatHub = $.connection.chatHub;
    $.connection.hub.logging = true;



    myChatHub.client.receivedNewMessage = function (username, message) {
        var newMessage = new _message( name, message);
            $scope.messages.push(_message);
            $scope.$apply();

        };


    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {

        $scope.addMessage = function () {
            myChatHub.server.addMessage($scope.username, $scope.message);
        };

    });

}]);
```

and libs

```
   <script src="scripts/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:*****/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

I used web tools on chrome, everything looked fine to me. I debugged the js and on jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js it showed me:

> SignalR: Connection must be started before data can be sent. Call
>   .start() before .send()

and I don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
  $scope.addMessage = function () {
    myChatHub.server.addMessage($scope.username, $scope.message);
  };
});
```

To:

```
$scope.addMessage = function () {
  myChatHub.server.addMessage($scope.username, $scope.message);
};

$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
 $scope.addMessage($scope.username, $scope.message);
});
```

The function declaration should NOT exist within the `start().done` context.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i still get this error  :    angular.js:11358 Error: SignalR: Connection must be started before data can be sent. Call .start() before .send()
    at Object.send (jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js:9)
    at invoke (jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js:9)
    at Object.addMessage (hubs:84)
    at h.$scope.addMessage (VM45 chatController.js:32)
    at angular.js:12133
    at f (angular.js:22518)
    at h.$eval (angular.js:14123)
    at h.$apply (angular.js:14221)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:22523)
    at HTMLButtonElement.c (angular.js:3013)

Comment: i fixed it.don't know how

Comment: hmmm I think angular was kick-starting something. also the path is usually `~/signalr/hubs`